# OpenCV Error: (addWeighted)operation is neither 'array op array'

Tags: python, arrays, opencv

The project that I work on uses opencv to get the image on webcam
The error starts with the function "addWeighted"

I found some errors about this function because of the different picture format, I printed the size and channel of the two pictures
(720, 1280, 3)
(720, 1280, 3)
And i don't know what is wrong
Here a part of my code

```
transparentImg = cv2.imread("transparentImg.png")

##.......##
output = transparentImg.copy()
while True:
    ref, img = cam.read()
    print(output.shape)
    print(transparentImg.shape)
    cv2.addWeighted(transparentImg, alpha, img, 1 - alpha,0, output)
    cv2.imshow('image', output)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

result:
(720, 1280, 3)
(720, 1280, 3)

Traceback (most recent call last):
cv2.addWeighted(transparentImg, alpha, img, 1 - alpha,0, output)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:669: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::arithm_op'

Comment: Likely, because your img has 3 channels and your transparentImg has 4 channels.

Comment: If you are sure about the dimensions of the two images, also check their types. They are both np.array, aren't they?